# const char* to int cast?

Tags: c++, casting, char, int

I suppose the behaviour of the following snippet is supposed to be undefined but I just wanted to make sure I am understanding things right.
Let's say we have this code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "mamut" - 8 << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

So what I think this does is (char*)((int)(const char*) - (int)), though the output after this is pretty strange, not that I expect it to make any real sense. So my question is about the casting between char* and int - is it undefined, or is there some logic behind it?

EDIT:
Let me just add this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    const char* a = "mamut";
    int b = int(a);
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << &a <<std::endl;
    // seems b!= &a
    for( int i = 0; i<100;i++)
    {
        std::cout<<(const char*)((int)a - i)<<std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
 }
```

The output after i gets big enough gives me a something like _Jv_RegisterClasses etc.
Just for the record:

```
std::cout << a - i << std::endl;
```

produces the same result as:

```
std::cout<<(const char*)((int)a - i)<<std::endl;
```

Comment: It's undefined behavior but not because of the reasons you think. Google pointer arithmetic.

Comment: You seem to assume that `const char*` is converted to `int` when you subtract `8`. The assumption is wrong.

Comment: Why is the assumption wrong? I mean you cannot add char*, as + is not defined for char* + char*.

Comment: Also your edit has nothing to do with the original question. Please just ask one question per post, make a new post if you have a different question.

Comment: The edit is pretty much the same program but with i getting bigger(basically you'll see other results apart from "mamut" - 8 ). I made the for cycle cause with each i it prints out the output I was talking about.

Comment: The first problem was because of accidental pointer arithmetic. The second problem seems to be related to the address format on your particular system, which doesn't fit in an int.

Comment: @lightxbulb You can add a pointer and an integer, and `"mamut" - 8` is equivalent to `&("mamut"[-8])`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no cast, you are merely telling cout that you want to print the string at the address of the string literal "mamut" minus 8 bytes. You are doing pointer arithmetic. cout will then print whatever happens to be at that address, or possibly crash & burn, since accessing arrays out of bounds leads to undefined behavior.

**EDIT**

Regarding the edit by the op: converting an address to `int` doesn't necessarily result in a correct number identical to the address. An address doesn't necessarily fit in an `int` and on top of that, `int` is a signed type and it doesn't make any sense to store addresses in signed types.

To guarantee a conversion from pointer to integer without losses, you need to use `uintptr_t` from stdint.h.

To quote the C standard 6.3.2.3 (I believe C++ is identical in this case):

> Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as
>   previously specified, the result is implementation-defined. If the
>   result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is
>   undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any
>   integer type.

Comment: The problem is that (int)a doesn't give me the address of a. Basically &a != (int)a. My question since the beginning was what does (int)a give me.

Comment: @lightxbulb I already answered that in a comment to your question. I'll add the comment to this answer for completeness.

Comment: So it is undefined behaviour and doing a cast (int)(const char*) actually has no logic behind it? I mean the cast doesn't produce any logical result?

Comment: @lightxbulb It is true that a cast from a pointer to the plain, dumb, signed `int` type never makes sense in any C or C++ program. However, it is not undefined behavior to do the cast itself. See cited text above.

Answer (score 1):

There is no casting going on. `"mamut"` is a pointer to characters, and `- 8` will do pointer arithmetic on it. You are right that it's undefined behavior, so even though the semantic behavior is pointer arithmetic, the runtime behavior can be literally anything.

Comment: Then why doesn't the address correspond to the number I get from (int)(const char*)?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Post more code to precisely illustrate your question. But I am trying to emphasize that UB means literally anything can happen. It doesn't need to be explained past UB. Remove the UB from your code and then we can dig in further.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing string starting from address of "mamut" minus 8 bytes till null terminator i.e. in total `8+5 = 13` chars